# Connecting Ubuntu 20.04 to ethernet without netplan

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I made a terrible mistake: while debugging a server, I ran `sudo apt-get -y remove libpng16-16 libglib2.0-0` locally, and it uninstalled just about *everything* including netplan and GNOME. I restarted the computer, logged in on via commandline and attempted to install GNOME, but it won't seem to connect to the internet. The output of `ip a` shows my ethernet interface is DOWN. I tried using netplan, but the command is not installed. How can I connect to the internet over ethernet without using netplan?

Comment: Does the command `ifconfig` work on your system?  If so, try `sudo ifconfig <interface> up` and see if it comes up.

Comment: @Terrance ifconfig works and the output shows the mac address, no inet value, no itnet6 value and says `device interupt 16` at the bottom

Comment: Try `dhclient <interface>` and see if it is able to pull DHCP from a DHCP server.

Comment: This worked: you are literally my hero.

Comment: One other thing, you might want to run `grep "remove " /var/log/dpkg.log` and see if it shows you all that was removed and maybe you can reinstall what is missing.

Comment: Sweet, this helps too. Thanks! Submit this as an answer and I'll mark it as solved!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the command `ifconfig` still works, you can run `sudo ifconfig <interface> up` to bring up the Ethernet.  Then run `dhclient <interface>` to renew a IP address for the Ethernet.

As for the packages that got removed, run `grep "remove " /var/log/dpkg.log` to show what was recently removed to help reinstall what is missing.